# Print Spooler is crashing in 480 dpi screen

Tags: screen, stock-android, printing

Please understand this question before marking this as duplicate.
In my phone, the **Print Spooler** app is working perfectly fine when the screen density is set to less than 400 dp. But, when I set the screen density to 400 dp or more, the app simply crashes whenever it is launched.

See the screenshots below :
Screen density less than 400 dp:

[image]

Screen density greater than or equal to 400dp:

[image]

Here is the adb log:

```
--------- beginning of crash
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.printspooler, PID: 1008
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Binary XML file line #273: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #273: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:424)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2419)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.onPrinterRegistryReady(PrintActivity.java:329)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.-com_android_printspooler_ui_PrintActivity_lambda$2(PrintActivity.java:320)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$-void_-com_android_printspooler_ui_PrintActivity_lambda$1_android_os_IBinder_documentAdapter_LambdaImpl0.run(PrintActivity.java)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.android.printspooler:drawable/ic_expand_more with resource ID #0x7f020005
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_expand_more.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:972)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:931)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4226)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:150)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
03-06 14:56:28.770  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:424)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2419)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.onPrinterRegistryReady(PrintActivity.java:329)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity.-com_android_printspooler_ui_PrintActivity_lambda$2(PrintActivity.java:320)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.printspooler.ui.PrintActivity$-void_-com_android_printspooler_ui_PrintActivity_lambda$1_android_os_IBinder_documentAdapter_LambdaImpl0.run(PrintActivity.java)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #22: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:771)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:731)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1229)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:188)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:116)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1229)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1202)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
03-06 14:56:28.780  1008  1008 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 36 more
```

I had also tried clearing the ***Print Spooler*** app's data and cache, but I was out of luck. Please help me out about what is the cause of this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Enable the developer mode and ADB in your phone, connect it via USB to a PC, instalal ADB on the PC and connect to your phone via `adb logcat`. Then use the app till it crashes, most likely you will see the Exception on the logcat output which describes the error reason.

Comment: Sorry for being late, but I learnt about ADB logging recently. I have edited my question, please review it.

Comment: I am sorry but it looks like the ´com.android.printspooler`app has a bug (it tries to load a dialog layout that has an error) and therefore crashes. As a user you can't do anything about this even with root permissions it would be difficult to fix this kind of error. You can only install the latest firmware for your device and pray that it fixes the problem.